# Row to column in SQL Server with dynamic number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My source data looks something like this

```
ID        Phone Type     Phone Number                                                                                                                                                                    
-------------------------------------
308820        P           8136542273
308820        F           8136541384
308820        P           8139108555
308820        P           8136842229
308820        F           8139108655
211111        P           6874598695
456788        F           5687659867
```

In the above data, `Phone type = P` is phone and `F` is fax.

I need to sort the data and then pick only one F type and one P type phone number and populate the data as below

```
ID         Fax Number    Phone Number
-------------------------------------
308820     8136541384    8136542273
211111                   6874598695
456788     5687659867
```

Can someone help me out how to achieve this. There can be n number of Phone Numbers and Fax numbers against one ID  but I need to sort it and pick the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, max(case when phone_type = 'F' then phone_number end) as fax,
       max(case when phone_type = 'P' then phone_number end) as phone
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Guys thanks for the response. The query which I created is below. The help I got above was used in my query below. However the problem is that in the Binary_CheckSum it randomly picks up a Phone number and as such again selects the same record.

What I am trying to find is that for a particular ID and AddressID combination has the iSActive flag or Phone Number or Fax number has changed so that I need to select that record and insert it in PrescriberLocation table.

```
select TESTID, ADDRESSID, max(PhoneNumber) as PhoneNumber,max(FaxNumber) as FaxNumber,'1' as isactive from (select distinct a.TESTID
, b.AddressId , CASE WHEN c.PhoneType = 'P'THEN C.PhoneNumber END PhoneNumber
, CASE WHEN c.PhoneType = 'F'THEN C.PhoneNumber END FaxNumber 
   ,'1' as isactive from stg_Address a inner join stg_AddressPhone c on a.TESTID = c.TESTID and a.AddressID = c.AddressID INNER  join pbmsys_new.dbo.sc_Address b on 
          upper(a.Address1) = upper(b.Address1) and upper(isnull(a.Address2,'')) = upper(b.Address2)  join pbmsys_new.[dbo].[dr_PrescriberLocation] d
          on a.TESTID = d.TESTID and b.AddressId = d.AddressId
          where BINARY_CHECKSUM(1,c.PhoneNumber, FaxNumber) != BINARY_CHECKSUM(d.IsActive,d.PhoneNumber,d.FaxNumber) and d.PrescriberLocationId = SELECT max(Z.PrescriberLocationId) as PrescriberLocationId FROM pbmsys_new.dbo.dr_PrescriberLocation Z where d.TESTID = z.TESTID and d.AddressId =z.AddressId))f group by TESTID, AddressId
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregate function and sub-query

```
select id,max(fax_Number) as fax_Number, max(phone_Number) as phone_Number
from
(select id, case when phone_type = 'F' then phone_number end as fax_Number,
       case when phone_type = 'P' then phone_number end as phone_Number
from yourtable
) as t group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to pick first value and not the max value then you can use it.

```
; with CTE1
As
(
select row_number() over (partition by id,phonetype order by ID) as Num,ID,
       case when phonetype = 'F' then PhoneNumber end as FaxNumber, 
       case when phonetype = 'P' then PhoneNumber end as PhoneNumber
       from ContactDetails
)
select ID,max(FaxNumber),max(PhoneNumber) 
from (select ID,FaxNumber,PhoneNumber from CTE1 where num = 1)as T2 
group by ID
```